# I need a disease or illness in young adults

Tags: diseases, medical

I'm writing a story that involves the main character finding out she has some kind of disease or illness and how she deals with it immediately after. She's 20 years old and has been healthy up to this point. I'm trying to find a disease I can use that isn't cancer. The disease itself isn't a super major part of the story but it'd be nice to have something that isn't insanely complicated. I'd prefer not to go into a ton of detail about the disease. It's a real world, modern day location.
If you have any ideas, these are the criteria:

1. Not cancer
2. Preferably an illness that has the likelihood of survival--not terminal but still something that has to be worried about
3. Doesn't require an immediate hospital stay
4. Not something that would have been noticeable from a young age/since birth--the character is just now being diagnosed with this

If there is any other information needed, please let me know.

Comment: Everybody loves Syphylis...or good ol' Malaria.

Comment: H1N1, 1918 variant.

Answer (score 2):

**Autoimmune disease.**

There are many.  20 year old woman is a very plausible person to get some of the more serious ones.  She is a little old for type 1 diabetes but diabetes is a doable deal, manageable, dangerous, with opportunities to advance the plot.

Other autoimmune diseases could include lupus (bonafide super scary disease of young women),  or multiple sclerosis, which can impair a person and leave them functional if that is what you are looking for.  Rheumatoid arthritis is painful and makes life more difficult but is usually not life threatening.

Here is a list.
https://www.niehs.nih.gov/health/topics/conditions/autoimmune/index.cfm

Comment: I had been thinking Lupus. Ya beat me to it.

Comment: Is it Lupus? - Dr. House.

Answer (score 0):

I think the disease that is currently (December 2020) public enemy number 1 fits all your criteria.

1. [Covid-19](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronavirus_disease_2019) is not cancer.
2. Most people survive [Covid-19](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronavirus_disease_2019) but there is chance you die from it.
3. Getting [Covid-19](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronavirus_disease_2019) does not automatically mean you need/will get hospitalized.
4. [Covid-19](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronavirus_disease_2019) did not exist until about a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

### Dramatic But Manageable and interesting/informative:

[Juvenile myoclonic epilepsy](https://www.epilepsy.com/learn/types-epilepsy-syndromes/juvenile-myoclonic-epilepsy)

[Bipolar disorder](https://www.ryanlichtsangbipolarfoundation.org/awareness/what-is-early-onset-bipolar-disorder/)

[Adult onset asthma](https://www.webmd.com/asthma/guide/adult-onset-asthma) although asthma is in several books I know.

[Type II diabetes](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/type-2-diabetes/symptoms-causes/syc-20351193) but this can get kind of complicated. It's becoming more prevalent in the teen/young adult population due to increasing levels of obesity.